# How to redirect to another action with object parameters in Yii?

Tags: php, yii

I have a structure like this:

```
public class CertController extends CController
{
   public function actionCreateAfterLabel(Label $labelInputs)
   {
   }
}

public class LabelController extends CController
{
   public function actionCreate(Label $label)
   {
      $this->redirect(array("Cert/CreateAfterLabel", 'labelInputs' => $label));
   }
}
```

This isn't working because redirect will only work with GET parameters, i.e. key/values with strings.  How can I make this work with passing objects instead?

Comment: I'm really dissatisfied with these solutions. Not a reflection of those answering, but rather a reflection of Yii itself.  If there's no way to redirect to another controller with object parameters, it seems like a really big oversight IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the Label object in session, then redirect and pull the object out of session in your cert controller.

Answer (score 1):

I think [CHttpSession](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpSession) is a better solution, but if you really need (or want) to use redirect parameters you can try [PHP Object Serialization](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php).